# Angular 6 Google adwords conversion

Tags: angular, google-ads-api

I would like to track google adwords conversions in my angular 6 app.
How can I implement a service or something like that to track that?

Best regards
Fredrik

Comment: This is an awesome question and I'm surprised it's not already answered... isn't Google contributors to Angular? I would think this would be baked-in, but I have yet to find anything. Looking forward to an easy, straight-forward implementation recommendation.

Answer (score -2):

1. Install the global site tag on every page of your website.

   Open the HTML for each page.

   Choose from the following options(A,B OR C):

   A. If you haven't installed the global site tag on your website, copy
   the tag below and paste it between the head tags ():

   Here's an example of the global site tag:

   ```
   <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Ads: CONVERSION_ID -->
     <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-CONVERSION_ID"></script>
     <script>
       window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
       function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
       gtag('js', new Date());

       gtag('config','AW-CONVERSION_ID');
     </script>
   ```

   See more guidelines on setting up the global site tag.

   B. If you installed the global site tag on your website from another
   Google product (example: Google Analytics) or from another Google
   Ads account, copy the 'config' command below and add it to every
   instance of the global site tag, right above the  end tag.

> gtag('config', 'AW-CONVERSION_ID');

C. If you or a manager account already installed the global site tag on
 your website while setting up the tag for another conversion action,
 make sure that the tag is on every page of your website and check
 that the 'config' command has this Google Ads account's conversion
 ID: AW-CONVERSION_ID

Save the changes to your webpages.

2. Install the event snippet on the conversion page. This is the page
   your customers reach on your website after they've completed a
   conversion — the "Thank you for your order" page, for example.

   Open the HTML for the conversion page.

   Copy the snippet below and paste it between the head tags
   () of the page, right after the global site tag.

> ```
> <!-- Event snippet for Example conversion page -->
> <script>
>   gtag('event', 'conversion', {'send_to': 'AW-CONVERSION_ID/AW-CONVERSION_LABEL',
>     'value': 1.0,
>     'currency': 'USD'
>   });
> </script>
> ```

Save the changes to your webpage.

Comment: in Angular app the <head> tag are only in the index.html page, it's not possible to add it in a single one